# TypeScript - migrate JavaScript function

Tags: typescript

I have a JavaScript helper function which allows to remove a property of an object :

```
removeProp(obj, prop) {
  const { [prop]: _, ...result } = obj;
  return result;
}
```

TypeScript version :

```
removeProp(obj: Object, prop: string): Object {
  // tslint:disable-next-line: no-shadowed-variable
  const { [prop]: _, ...result } = obj;
  return result;
}
```

1- I have a lint error : `type 'Object' has no index signature corresponding to type 'string' tslint` in `[prop]`.

2- How i can initialize `result` variable with the right type if `obj` is a generic (takes all properties of the generic type - the removed property) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the function generic, with a generic parameter (lets call in `T`) to represent the type of the object and a second parameter (lets call it `K`) that should be a `keyof T`. For the return type you can use `Omit<T, K>` which will remove a key from a given type (although strictly speaking you can leave the return type blank and it will be correctly inferred)

```
function removeProp<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, prop: K): Omit<T, K> {
  const { [prop]: _, ...result } = obj;
  return result;
}

let o = removeProp({ a: 1, b: 2}, "b")
```

A version that works on 3.1 can't use spread (as spread with generic type parameters is not supported in that version, that was allowed in 3.2) and has to define `Omit` as that did not exist in 3.1 either (added in 3.5)

```
type Omit<T, K extends PropertyKey> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>
function removeProp<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, prop: K): Omit<T, K> {
  const result = Object.assign({}, obj);
  delete result[prop]
  return result;
}

let o = removeProp({ a: 1, b: 2}, "b");
console.log(o);
```

Comment: I have 2 lint errors `Cannot find name 'Omit'` and `Rest types may only be created from object types` . Being I am on TypeScript 3.1 I understand the `Omit` error but not the second error

Comment: @MouadEnnaciri both of those errors happen because you are in 3.1 the latest version is 3.5 and the code works with that. I can provide a backward compatible version but it can't use spread to remove the property.  Correctly typing spread on generic types happened in 3.2

Comment: I understand, that it is the version compatible the v3.1?

Comment: @MouadEnnaciri i added a version for 3.1. All ts releases are mostly compatible, but they all also have a number of breaking changes, upgrading might yield new errors as the type system becomes stricter in newer versions. Although if it compiles I expect it to work as it did before.

Comment: I would like to avoid the `delete` operator but I mark the question as resolved being the limitation caused by my TS version. Thanks